# Set iterator_bracket_proxy for boost::iterator_adapter

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I try to make a random access iterator `It`.

The indexing operation of `It` should return a `Node`.

But it doesn't. How to make it do that?

Test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    explicit Node(const T index) : index_(index) {}
    const T index_;
};

template<typename T>
class It
        : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
                It<T>, // Derived
                boost::counting_iterator<T>, // Base
                Node<T>, // Value
                std::random_access_iterator_tag, // CategoryOrTraversal
                Node<T>, // Reference
                boost::use_default  // Difference
        > {
protected:
    using self_type = It<T>;
    using node_type = Node<T>;
public:
    explicit It(const T& x) : self_type::iterator_adaptor_(x){}

    Node<T> operator*() const {
        // Dereferencing gives a index instead of a reference.
        auto& base_iterator = this->base_reference();
        return Node<T>(*base_iterator);
    }
protected:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
};

int main() {
    It<int> a(10);
    std::cout << (*a).index_ << "\n";
    // a[4] is a
    // class boost::iterators::detail
    //     ::operator_brackets_proxy<It<int> >
    // instead of a Node<int>.
    std::cout << a[4].index_ << "\n";
}
```

Error:

```
error: ‘boost::iterators::detail
    ::operator_brackets_result<It<int>, Node<int>, Node<int> >::type 
{aka class boost::iterators::detail
    ::operator_brackets_proxy<It<int> >}’ 
has no member named ‘index_’
     std::cout << a[4].index_ << "\n";
                       ^~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation [`operator[]`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iterator/doc/facade-and-adaptor.html#id23)

> Writable iterators built with iterator_facade implement the semantics required by the preferred resolution to [issue 299](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#299) and adopted by proposal [n1550](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2003/n1550.htm):
>   <sup>(1)</sup>**the result of `p[n]` is an object convertible to the iterator's `value_type`**, and `p[n] = x` is equivalent to `*(p + n) = x` (Note: This result object may be implemented as a proxy containing a copy of `p+n`). This approach will work properly for any random-access iterator regardless of the other details of its implementation.
>   <sup>(2)</sup>**A user who knows more about the implementation of her iterator is free to implement an `operator[]` that returns an lvalue in the derived iterator class; it will hide the one supplied by `iterator_facade` from clients of her iterator.**

As of <sup>(1)</sup>, you may write:

```
std::cout << static_cast<Node<int>>(a[4]).index_ << "\n";
```

Or <sup>(2)</sup> implement `operator[]`:

```
Node<T> operator[](std::ptrdiff_t n) const {
    return *std::next(*this,n);
}
```

```
std::cout << a[4].index_ << "\n";
```

or write instead:

```
std::cout << std::next(a,4)->index_ << "\n";
std::cout << (a+4)->index_ << "\n";
```